# Adjusting the size of the labelling arrows and normal distribution curve

Tags: pgfplots

I want to have the diagram like the below:
[image]
So far I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
    
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={<-},]
        \begin{axis}[
            no markers, 
            domain=0:6, 
            samples=100,
            ymin=0,
            axis lines*=left, 
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, 
            width=12cm,
            xtick=\empty, 
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, 
            clip=false, 
            axis on top,
            grid = major,
            hide y axis
            ]
            
            \begin{scope}[yshift=-\pgflinewidth]
                \clip (axis cs:1,0) rectangle (axis cs:2,0.24);
                \addplot [draw=none,fill=orange] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
            \end{scope}
            
            \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(1,1,7)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,1,1.65)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{gauss(1,1,1)}
            
            \draw [very thick, blue]  (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,\valueB);
            \draw [very thick, blue]  (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,\valueA);
            \draw [very thick, blue]  (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,\valueC);
            
            \node[below] at (axis cs:3,0)  {0}; 
            \node[coordinate,pin=86:{Probability distribution of expected returns in the set period}]
            at (axis cs:4,0.25) {};
            \node[coordinate,pin=100:{$\alpha$}]
            at (axis cs:1.4,0.1) {};
            \node[coordinate,pin=270:{Expected Shortfall}]
            at (axis cs:1.6,0) {};
            \node[coordinate,pin=86:{Value at Risk}]
            at (axis cs:2,0) {};
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which is producing something close to what I want though the size of the normal curve, the size of labelling arrows, the positioning of labelling arrows and the labelling text (e.g Probability of distribution of returns... text is extending into the right side which is something I do not desire) requires some adjustments. The picture below shows the output obtained using the the MWE:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change arrow tips I suggest loading the `arrows.meta` library. Then you can use `every pin edge/.style={Stealth-}`.

To split the pin label into multiple lines, it must be aligned. You can make other adjustments to the pin position in the same place:

```
\node[coordinate, 
    pin={[align=right, anchor=south, pin distance=5mm]
      above right:{Probability distribution\\of Returns expected\\in the set period}}]
  at (axis cs:4,0.25) {};
```

[image]

You can use `xscale` to make the plot wider.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
    
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{gauss}{3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{1/(#3*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((#1-#2)^2)/(2*#3^2))}%
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every pin edge/.style={Stealth-},]
        \begin{axis}[xscale=1.5,
            no markers, 
            domain=0:6, 
            samples=100,
            ymin=0,
            axis lines*=left, 
            every axis y label/.style={at=(current axis.above origin),anchor=south},
            every axis x label/.style={at=(current axis.right of origin),anchor=west},
            height=5cm, 
            width=12cm,
            xtick=\empty, 
            ytick=\empty,
            enlargelimits=false, 
            clip=false, 
            axis on top,
            grid = major,
            hide y axis
            ]
            
            \begin{scope}[yshift=-\pgflinewidth]
                \clip (axis cs:1,0) rectangle (axis cs:2,0.24);
                \addplot [draw=none,fill=orange] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
            \end{scope}
            
            \addplot [very thick,cyan!50!black] {gauss(x, 3, 1)};
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valueB{gauss(1,1,7)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valueA{gauss(1,1,1.65)}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\valueC{gauss(1,1,1)}
            
            \draw [very thick, blue]  (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs:1,\valueB);
            \draw [very thick, blue]  (axis cs:2,0) -- (axis cs:2,\valueA);
            \draw [very thick, blue]  (axis cs:3,0) -- (axis cs:3,\valueC);
            
            \node[below] at (axis cs:3,0)  {0}; 
            \node[coordinate, pin={[align=right, anchor=south, pin distance=5mm]above right:{Probability distribution\\of Returns expected\\in the set period}}]
            at (axis cs:4,0.25) {};
            \node[coordinate,pin=100:{$\alpha$}]
            at (axis cs:1.4,0.1) {};
            \node[coordinate,pin=270:{Expected Shortfall}]
            at (axis cs:1.6,0) {};
            \node[coordinate,pin=86:{Value at Risk}]
            at (axis cs:2,0) {};
        \end{axis}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```